# One word for monthly maintenance payment

Tags: single-word-requests

If I am the landlord, and I am collecting monthly payments (in addition to the rent) from the tenants to save them for future (lift, light, gates, etc.) maintenance. Is there a single word/phrase with this meaning for the payment collection?

Comment: In the UK it is usually called a "service charge".

Comment: (condo) fees in the US.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an accounting practice (and account category) that is peculiar to a few areas and requires local knowledge.

Comment: Why do you split it out? If you collect $1500 from the tenants each month then their rent is $1500.  It doesn’t matter if that amount includes money for maintenance, mortgage, taxes, or whatever.  It’s all just rent.

Comment: @Jim they are additional costs that weren't existing at the time of signing the contracts.

Comment: @Diaa What do you suppose the regular rent payments are for if not for those things?

Comment: @PhilSweet I am not supposing anything. I am just asking if there is a word for this meaning on this site.

Comment: A good rental contract would prevent a landlord from imposing  these kinds of “maintenance fees”.

Comment: What the correct legal term for such fees is, and whether it is legal to impose them (as something separate from the rent), in the first place, is a jurisdiction-specific *legal* question. Such questions are outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Property Management Fees](https://www.rentecdirect.com/blog/property-management-fees-how-much-do-property-managers-charge/) are something that you as landlord would pay to a property management company and would include some escrow for maintenance (including emergency maintenance.

Since you are keeping these payments in escrow to pay for routine maintenance, though, I would simply call them [Common Area Maintenance Fees](http://Common%20Area%20Maintenance) although these are normally for commercial properties

Comment: escrow for maintenance? escrow? condo fees are not put into escrow. The extra cash is put into an interest-bearing account to be used for major repairs. And there is another for regular services, like trash (rubbish).

Comment: Escrow is something of value held by a third party designated for a specific purpose (like maintenance).  I did stretch the definition a bit so that it included the money held by the OP

Comment: The escrow account is for the one-month or two-month security (deposit, AmE). And the fees on these jointly-owned properties (forget the BrE term) paid monthly are not just for common area "maintenance". They are mostly for services (water, electrical, trash removal, etc.)

Comment: There seems to be some confusion, and perhaps disagreement,  about the meaning of the term "escrow".   What term would you recommend instead meaning "monies held in trust for a designated purpose"?

Comment: That is what escrow means. I am not contesting what it means; I am contesting its validity in the context of this question. It's like an accounting footnote or something. Also, "maintenance'. They are really fees for services provided by the property owners association via a management company the services of which it has retained.

Comment: Good thing that I didn't actually suggest that the OP use the term "escrow" then.

Comment: It is essential to the notion of an escrow that the funds are held by a third party. It is self-contradictory to speak of an escrow without a third party.

Answer (score -1):

I have used the word **upkeep** fee, cost or just $00.00

Answer (score -1):

A sum of money paid in advance to cover possible future expenses (and presumably returned if unused) is a ***deposit***.

> **[deposit](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/deposit)**
>
> > 2.1  A returnable sum payable on the hire or rental of something, to cover possible loss or damage.
> >     *‘a refundable €100 deposit is payable on arrival at the villa’*

> **[Deposit](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/deposit.asp)**
>
> A deposit is a financial term that has multiple definitions. The first
>   definition is a transaction involving a transfer of funds to another
>   party for safekeeping. The second definition is a portion of funds
>   that is used as security or [collateral](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/collateral.asp) for the delivery of a
>   good.

Comment: @Lambie The question says absolutely nothing about "*fees paid by individual property owners in a condo*". It describes payments made in advance and saved to be used against future maintenance expenses. Expenses that could be incurred or not. Payments made by tenants - not property owners. In a condo? Could be, could be not. Makes no difference. I have no idea how you got from here to there.

Comment: @Lambie The OP has posed the question quite clearly. If you know better what their situation is and what their question should be, take it up with them.

Comment: @Lambie Enjoy. Though you have made it clear that your quarrel is with the OP, not me. Now please quit this, because you are as close to trolling me as one can be.